# cvxpy - cannot solve a weighted SDP problem

Tags: python, optimization, cvxpy

I want to test a a weighted SDP problem in cvxpy, namely `min_{X > 0} | P * X - B |^2`, where `*` is the Hadamard product. I started with the simple case with P being the identity matrix. This is the code I wrote for the problem.

```py
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np
import random
##parameters
random.seed(1)
n = 50
CN = 10
#generate real A
D = np.diag(1000 * np.logspace(-np.log(CN), 0, n))
Q, R = np.linalg.qr(np.random.normal(size = (n,n)))
A = Q @ D @ Q
P = np.ones((n,n))
PA = np.multiply(P, A)
X = cp.Variable((n,n), symmetric=True)
X.value = np.identity(n)
constraints = [X >> 0]
prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(0.5 * cp.norm(P @ A - PA, 'fro')),
                  constraints)
prob.solve()

X.value
```

I used `@` in place of `*` because matrix multiplication with identity is equal to that with Hardamard product ( I also can't find the atom function for element-wise multiplication in cvxpy; if someone knows it, it would be really helpful if you can inform me).

After testing out, I consistently get the optimal value for X as the zero matrix. I think there must be some error in my implementation but I cannot tell which is wrong. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: please provide a complete  [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example").

Comment: literally just import numpy and cvxpy and initialize n nnd CN, but here you go

Comment: Hardamard??????

Comment: Your optimization variable X does not appear in the objective. The objective is constant.